# Android Studio 2.2 Duplicate files exception

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib

My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.falcode.clientservertestapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.xmlrpc:xmlrpc-client:3.1.3'
}
```

Before I had error:
"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
>       File1: C:\Users\CeoFalcode.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.xmlrpc\xmlrpc-client\3.1.3\e486ad917028b52265610206fb5a1e2b5914b94b\xmlrpc-client-3.1.3.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\CeoFalcode.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.xmlrpc\xmlrpc-common\3.1.3\415daf1f1473a947452588906dc9f5b3575fb44d\xmlrpc-common-3.1.3.jar"

I add some exclude line in `packagingOne{}`, but after I run into another error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process

and 82 lines report of error, where said "Recompile this lib from sources". I have no idea on how to solve this.

82 lines or errors:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
>
> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>
> Error:(org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcCommonsTransport$1) that doesn't come with an
>
> Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>
> Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>
> Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>
> Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>
> Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>
> Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>
> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>
> Error:(org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcCommonsTransport$1$1) that doesn't come with an
>
> Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>
> Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>
> Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>
> Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>
> Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>
> Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>
> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>
> Error:(org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcCommonsTransport$1$2) that doesn't come with an
>
> Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>
> Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>
> Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>
> Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>
> Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>
> Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>
> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>
> Error:(org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcLiteHttpTransport$1) that doesn't come with an
>
> Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>
> Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>
> Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>
> Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>
> Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>
> Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>
> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>
> Error:(org.apache.xmlrpc.client.util.ClientFactory$1) that doesn't come with an
>
> Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>
> Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>
> Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>
> Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>
> Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>
> Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>
> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>
> Error:(org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker$1) that doesn't come with an
>
> Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>
> Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>
> Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>
> Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>
> Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>
> Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
>
> Error:trouble processing "javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.class":
>
> Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
>
> Error:when not building a core library.
>
> Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
>
> Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
>
> Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
>
> Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
>
> Error:going on.
>
> Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
>
> Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
>
> Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
>
> Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
>
> Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
>
> Error:It is also often of questionable legality.
>
> Error:If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
>
> Error:appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
>
> Error:distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
>
> Error:the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
>
> Error:If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
>
> Error:building an application, then be forewarned that your application
>
> Error:will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
>
> Error:prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
>
> Error:application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
>
> Error:system. You will be to blame for this problem.
>
> Error:If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
>
> Error:core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
>
> Error:repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
>
> Error:your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
>
> Error:conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
>
> Error:you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
>
> Error:that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
>
> Error:lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
>
> Error:1 error; aborting
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process

Comment: "and 82 lines report of error" -- we cannot help you with those 82 lines, since we do not know what they are. If I had to guess, your `xmlrpc` library is not Android-compatible. [This one](https://github.com/gturri/aXMLRPC) reportedly works on Android.

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev thank you very much. You advice was the very what I needed